# How to know the number the last generated page?

Tags: page-numbering, conditionals

I would like to replace

```
\AtEndDocument{
\doSomething
}
```

by

```
\AtEndDocument{
if (page == 1) {
    \doSomething
}
else
{
    \doSomethingElse
}
}
```

How can I know the index of the last page generated? What is the syntax to be used to do such an `if-else` statement?

Comment: You've been a member for four years now and can't provide a MWE starter ?

Comment: Look at the questions I've asked before: I usually always give a MWE. I thought it was not necessary here.

Comment: `\usepackage{ifthen} \AtEndDocument{\ifthenelse{\thepage = 1}{1 page}{multiple pages}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `page` counter is sometimes unreliable, but this should work for not too sophisticated stuff. It will fail of course, if the code adds additional typesetting.

A better approach would use the `lastpage` package, but there's not much information, therefore I don't apply `lastpage` here.

```
\documentclass{article}

\AtEndDocument{%
\ifnum\value{page}= 1
This is a short document
\else
This is a longer document
\fi
}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[5]


\end{document}
```

Comment: My stuff is very sophisticated but I think this will be enough. Thanks!